# pls help me to get this prime number code right

Tags: python, function, loops, numbers

```
n = int(input('Enter number '))
def prime(n):
    for i in range (2,int(n-1)):
        if (n%i)==0:
            print('no is not prime')
            break
        else: 
            print('no is  prime')
            break
prime(n)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will display prime numbers from 900 to 1000

```
lower = 900
upper = 1000

print("Prime numbers between", lower, "and", upper, "are:")

for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
# all prime numbers are greater than 1
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
           if (num % i) == 0:
               break
        else:
           print(num)
```